# How to delete an In-App product from Google Play Store Developer Console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have accidentally input In-App product on Google Play Store with an incorrect id. The inputted id is already associated with another product (That i have to enter in my In-App products list). 
Google's Developer Console is not displaying any delete button in the In-App Products section.

Is there any way i can Delete the inputted Product ? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: **Word of warning**!!! Be careful about deleting a product. Once you have, you can never ever use that product id again. There is no undo. There is no going back. I think this is stupid policy on Google's part. For instance I was using a naming scheme (e.g. gold##) and accidentally deleted "gold12". Now my scheme is completely botched and I will have to go back delete all my gold products and create new ones like "gold-12", adding the dash. None of these products have been published yet either. Just a waste of my time and Google's resources.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can delete that and its simple. You need to click on product to and go to details of that product. Then click on product status active and you can see two options deactivate and delete. Select delete.
Note: You can't reuse any deleted item again.

Comment: I will verify this option and comeback to you.

Comment: @SalmanMuhammadAyub you should mark this as correct so that others and get quick solution. Thanks

Comment: Note that you can’t delete subscription products that way (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783694/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715489/).