# "You must have account hold and restore implemented in your app by November 1, 2020." -what does this message mean in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

There is a message on top of the **Dashboard** of my every app in **Google Play Console** saying:

`You must have account hold and restore implemented in your app by November 1, 2020. Subscription pause and resubscribe will also be enabled by default, unless you explicitly opt out.`

I don't have any paid apps in my **Google Play Console** account yet, I am confused about this.

Is this message applicable only for paid apps? If not, when or for whom this message will be applicable and what he/she will need to do then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: It means they can't stop doing stupid pointless changes otherwise they would be fired for not doing anything

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As mentioned in [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-features-to-acquire-and-retain-subscribers.html),

> **Account hold** is a state the user enters after a renewal fails due to a
> payment issue. During account hold, the user loses access to the
> subscription while Google notifies the user and retries the payment
> method.
>
> **Restore** enables users to resume auto-renewals after they have
> canceled the subscription but before the subscription expires.

So you have to make changes **only** if you have **subscriptions** in your app and using [Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) to manage them.

!! Please notice that in the new [payments policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9992660), Google **enforces** the app providers to use **Google Play’s billing system** if they are selling subscriptions, virtual items, app features, or cloud services.

Comment: I have in-app purchase on my free app, but i do not support subscription model. Do i need to handle this?

Comment: @ShashankDegloorkar no, in-app purchase is not affected, only apps with subscriptions need to be updated.

Comment: Why couldn't Google explain this properly in their Dashboard warning? It's not even clear in the blog post. It's annoying to have to spend time to google for this answer.

Comment: The link you provided to the new billing policy mentions only in-app purchases, not subscriptions, as far as I can see.

Comment: @syonip Subscriptions are part of in-app purchases.. read point 2.a in the payments policy .. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9992660

Comment: We used to support subscription, and now not support. But can not remove them according below this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783694/how-to-remove-subscription-from-product-list-in-developer-console-and-what-will

Do i need to handle this?

Comment: @MujtabaFR Does that mean that apps that require external subscription like Spotify, Netflix, Audible are violating policy?

Comment: In giving the above answer, two paragraphs are quoted from the Android Developers Blog, one paragraph on Account Hold and one on Restore.  The prior sentence before the two quoted paragraphs reads "Account hold and restore will both be mandatory for all developers."  Personally, I feel that it is a bit of a leap of faith to draw the conclusion from this Android Developers Blog alone that a free app is exempt.

Answer (score 18):

After a long, long time of searching, I finally found an official answer from someone affiliated with Google (provided two days ago).

"If your Android app sells subscription products, then you will need to make sure these subscription features (account hold, restore, pause, and resubscribe) are supported. If your Android app does not sell subscription products, you will not need to worry about this upcoming change."

The answer is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170592154

Comment: So they shifted this from their Store UI onto developers; never a wise choice; they will have to enforce this.

Answer (score 9):

Whether you have a paid app or in-app purchases or you use any external payment gateway you will not face any issues unless you have any subscription model from Google Play Billing.

Comment: I don't have any subscription/in-app in my app, but still this warning appears. Do I need to do anything special or just ignore this warning?

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq this is my question as well.  My app is completely free and has never had any subscriptions or purchases, but the warning message on Play Console was concerning because it sounded like I was required to make a change.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq you can just ignore this warning!